# MySQL 5.5 replication setup on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql-replication, ubuntu-12.04, mysql5.5

The following `master-master` configuration worked on MySQL Server 5.1.x(Ubuntu 10.04).

### Master1(192.168.2.80)

```
##################################
#MySQL Replication
##################################
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
event_scheduler = ON
max_connections = 500
max_connect_errors = 1000

server-id = 10
replicate-same-server-id = 0
auto-increment-increment = 10
auto-increment-offset = 1

master-host = 192.168.2.81
master-user = repli
master-password = secret
master-connect-retry = 60

binlog-format = MIXED
#binlog-ignore-db = information_schema
#binlog-ignore-db = lb1

#max_binlog_size = 500M
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin
log-bin-index = /var/log/mysql/bin-log.index

log-slave-updates
report-host = 192.168.2.80
replicate-ignore-db = information_schema
replicate-ignore-db = lb2
replicate-ignore-db = performance_schema

relay_log_space_limit = 3G
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/relay.log
relay-log-index = /var/log/mysql/relay-log.index
##################################
```

### Master2(192.168.2.81)

```
##################################
#MySQL Replication
##################################
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
event_scheduler = ON
max_connections = 500
max_connect_errors = 1000

server-id = 20
replicate-same-server-id = 0
auto-increment-increment = 10
auto-increment-offset = 2

master-host = 192.168.2.80
master-user = repli
master-password = secret
master-connect-retry = 60

binlog-format = MIXED
#binlog-ignore-db = information_schema
#binlog-ignore-db = lb2

#max_binlog_size = 500M
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin
log-bin-index = /var/log/mysql/bin-log.index

log-slave-updates
report-host = 192.168.2.81
replicate-ignore-db = information_schema
replicate-ignore-db = lb1
replicate-ignore-db = performance_schema

relay_log_space_limit = 3G
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/relay.log
relay-log-index = /var/log/mysql/relay-log.index
##################################
```

Now it's NOT working with MySQL Server 5.5(ubuntu 12.04). I mean to say when I restart the mysql service with the above configuration, mysql service takes long time to start and dont' start at all. Nothing in mysql logs and are empty. I tried killing mysql and starting it again but still it's not starting and if I remove the above replication configuration, then it starts usually.

What's wrong I am doing with mysql 5.5?. I am planning to setup a four node cluster with mysql replication on Ubuntu servers for HA and failover. Is `Ubuntu 12.04` and `MySQL 5.5` recommended for production use?

Need your inputs. Thank you!

### Update 1

After commenting the following `master-*` lines on both the master, MySQL starts normally and replication works.

```
#master-host = 192.168.2.xx
#master-user = repli
#master-password = secret
#master-connect-retry = 60
```

Then how to specify the master server on slaves?. Is `CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='192.168.2.xx', MASTER_USER='repli', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret',...` enough?. Are MySQL 5.5.24 & ubuntu 12.04 production ready?

Comment: Try to start it not in daemon mode, then you might see what error it is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean to say when I restart the mysql service with the above
>   configuration, mysql service takes long time to start and dont' start
>   at all. Nothing in mysql logs and are empty.

Did you specify [`log-error`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-error) option in `/etc/my.cnf`?

> After commenting the following `master-*` lines on both the master,
>   MySQL starts normally and replication works.
>
> ```
> #master-host = 192.168.2.xx
> #master-user = repli
> #master-password = secret
> #master-connect-retry = 60
> ```
>
> Then how to specify the master server on slaves?. Is `CHANGE MASTER TO
>   MASTER_HOST='192.168.2.xx', MASTER_USER='repli',
>   MASTER_PASSWORD='secret',...` enough?.

The [`master-*`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html) options are remove in MySQL 5.5. Sure, `CHANGE MASTER TO` is enough because the value are saved to the `master.info` file.

> Are MySQL 5.5.24 & ubuntu 12.04 production ready?

Yes. But take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-x.html) for more information.